# Rename tag maven-toolchains to maven-toolchains-plugin

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I am requesting [maven-toolchains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-toolchains) be renamed to [maven-toolchains-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-toolchains-plugin) to make it consistent with other [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) plugin tags.

Comment: [[tag:maven-archetype]] is not named with a "-plugin" suffix; should it be? What about [[tag:maven-profiles]]? [[tag:maven-central]]? [[tag:maven-publish]]? [[tag:maven-cargo]]? [[tag:maven-scm]]?

Comment: [The official list] https://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html. Yes to: archetype, cargo, scm. No to: profiles, central, publish.